# Xbox One Controller not identifiable in Windows 11

Tags: usb, drivers, windows-11, xbox-one

A friend's Xbox One controller suddenly stopped working on Windows 11 so I've been helping to troubleshoot.

Connecting the controller to the Windows 11 PC results in a `USB Device could not be identified` message. In Device Manager the controller shows up under `Other Devices > Controller` instead of the usual placement under the `Xbox Controllers` or even `Human Interface Devices`.

Through some googling found some troubleshooting suggestions but have tried them all with no good result. This includes the usual steps of running the Windows troubleshooter, uninstalling the controller drivers through Device Manager and then trying to reinstall both automatically via USB connection (still showed up as "could not be identified") and selecting the default drivers via Device Manager manually. The obvious steps were taken too, like trying another cable, different port, different controller. Through those steps we were able to discover that it seems specifically Xbox Controllers face the issue as we were able to get a PlayStation 4 controller working through the same port and same cable, but every Xbox controller had the same problem as the first. The problem was the same over wired *and* wireless connections; trying to pair over Bluetooth the Xbox controller is listed as usual in the `Add device` list, but after initial connection just stops working or disconnects.

Reaching the end of my abilities with Windows I tried a system restore to a couple of weeks ago, before the issue started, but that resulted in the same problem. As a last ditch effort I reinstalled the drivers for the USB controller of the PC's motherboard hoping that'd restart *something* into recognising the device, but still nothing.

I'd like a clearer idea of how I can completely reinstall whatever drivers govern the recognition/connection for these Xbox controllers, but haven't been able to find anything concrete online so far, even where to *get* the correct drivers without them being auto-installed by Windows, any ideas?

Comment: Run the Windows Hardware and Devices Troubleshooter. If possible, try to [Update your Xbox Wireless Controller](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/controller/update-xbox-wireless-controller).

Comment: If you reinstalled Windows and had the same issue then it’s either the USB cable you used with multiple Xbox controllers or you have multiple dead Xbox One controllers. Support for Xbox One controllers is built-into Windows 10. There really isn’t any way to repair the functionality other than repair Windows or replace the controller (I suspect the controller simply died since PS4 controllers worked)

Comment: The controllers all work on my PC but specifically aren't recognised on my friend's, so I know for sure it's an issue on their end, all the controllers we've tried are confirmed working on other Windows systems and the Xbox One console too.